# bean class instantiation in spring for a class without default constructor

Tags: spring, constructor, default-constructor

I am using a third party library class XYZ as an argument in my model. XYZ does not have a default constructor. So spring is not able to create bean for it giving error message as

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; 

nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: 

Could not instantiate bean class [org.abc.def.XYZ]: No default constructor found;nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.abc.def.XYZ./<init/>()
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
```

What can I do to resolve this ? I can't add default constructor to XYZ.

I added the following in my dispatcher servlet, but it still don't works.

```
<bean name="token" class="org.abs.def.Xyx">
    <constructor-arg name="arg1" value="val1"/>
    <constructor-arg name="arg2" value="val2"/>
    <constructor-arg name="arg3" value="val3"/>
</bean>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can define it in the XML file as a spring bean passing all necessary parameters to instantiate it.

sample:

```
<bean id="xyz" class="com.a.b.Xyz" >
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="anotherBean"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="12"/> 
</bean>
```

Comment: I have tried doing that, but it does not work. It's throwing same error!

Comment: where and how did you add it? How do you initialize your spring context? What version of spring are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide `<constructor-arg>` elements in your application context config file, as described in [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-factory-collaborators).