# Spring wire up - default constructor not found

Tags: java, spring, code-injection, default-constructor

I am attempting to do constructor injection into the bean below and I keep getting the default constructor not found error - Caused by: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: my.package.MyBean.<init>()`.

If I add a default constructor in, the error goes away, but obviously this is not what I want to do.

I would like to understand why the simple `xml` mapping does not match with the constructor I have.

I know this question has been asked in some form before, but none of those answers help me in my situation.

**TIA.**

```
@Component
@Scope("singleton")
public class MyBean {

    private Map<String, ResourceManager> rm;

    public MyBean(final Map<String, ResourceManager> rm) {
        this.rm = rm;
    }
...
}
```

**XML**

```
<bean id="mybean" class="my.package.MyBean">
    <constructor-arg>
        <util:map>
            <entry key="MANAGER1" value-ref="manager1" />
            <entry key="MANAGER2" value-ref="manager2" />
        </util:map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="manager1".....</bean>

<bean id="manager2".....</bean>
```

Comment: You can do it without a default constructor. But I haven't wired a Map so I don't know if this is the proper way to do that for a constructor argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar answere is been given for the same problem, may be you are hitting the same issue ?

[Does Spring require all beans to have a default constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492652/does-spring-require-all-beans-to-have-a-default-constructor)

[bean class instantiation in spring for a class without default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649237/bean-class-instantiation-in-spring-for-a-class-without-default-constructor)

Try marking the constructor @Autowired.

Comment: Thanks, it was actually the @Autowired that was missing!

Comment: This was just the answer I needed as well. Although in my case, I opted for @Inject on the constructor.